# CRM: Can't update OriginatingLeadId of Contact

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I've expirienced a very odd behaviour of my CRM 2011 API. When I try to update `originatingleadid` field of contact from one value to another nothing happes. No any errors in code, so when executing code everything looks perfect. But the value doesn't really changes.

I wrote a simple method to test it and have got same result.
Here is it.

```
class Program
{
    private static IOrganizationService service;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var contactId = Guid.Parse("B5A832D6-93DD-E611-ABAC-005056810E95");
        var leadId = Guid.Parse("8306E695-94DD-E611-ABAC-005056810E95");
        getService("admin", "password", "domain");

        SetOriginatingLead(contactId, leadId);
    }

    private static void SetOriginatingLead(Guid contactId, Guid leadId)
    {
        var entity = service.Retrieve("contact", contactId, 
new ColumnSet("originatingleadid"));
        var targetlead = new EntityReference("lead", leadId);
        entity["originatingleadid"] = targetlead;
        service.Update(entity);
        return;
    }

    private static void getService(string login, string password, string domain)
    {
        if (service != null)
            return;

        var cred = new ClientCredentials();
        cred.Windows.ClientCredential = 
new NetworkCredential(login, password, domain);
        service = new OrganizationServiceProxy(new 
Uri(@"http://crm/organisation/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc"), null, cred, null);
            return;
    }
}
```

Please, tell me where am I mistaken.

Comment: You are probably modifying the primary key.  So you may be creating another entry with the correction, or the database isn't allowing the primary key to get modified.

Comment: @jdweng, no, it is not the primary key in Contact entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot update the value of `OriginatingLeadId`. This can be seen in the EntityMetadata.xlsx file from the [SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=50032).

[image: OriginatingLeadId IsValidForUpdate=False]

Comment: So it can be set (first time) and then never be changed? (Except editing the value in db)

Comment: Correct: It is automatically set when you qualify a lead and a contact is created. You should never edit values directly in the database.

Comment: To clarify this answer: one can set the originatingleadid when you create the entity. You just cant set it when you update the entity. So make sure you get your create done right! (You dont have to qualify a lead to make sure this is set correctly in code)